# Show content of type A in content of type B based on shared taxonomy term using views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to show content of type A (products) in the middle of contents of type B(Producers), however I do not want to use Node reference since it's an overkill to make it happen with lots of products.

So far I have a Vocabulary which both content type share, so I thought if I choose a single taxonomy term when creating the contents of each type, I can relate them using views to each other based on that shared taxonomy.

Anyways so far no luck, I appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a block view to show content of type A (products), add a contextual filter `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`, provide default value with PHP:

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
return $node->field_term['und'][0]['tid'];
```

You can add safeguards, like `is_int(arg(1))`, `is_object($node)`, `$node->type == "product"`, etc. You don't need to if you add the block to a region and set it to be displayed on nodes of type B (producers) only.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've achieved the same without the use of PHP code: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180086/show-nodes-of-other-content-type-that-share-a-common-term-with-depth