# Show nodes of other content type that share a common term (with depth)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have two content types: *sector* and *product*. Both share terms from the same vocabulary, called *branch*.

A *sector node* should list all *product nodes* that share the same term(s) (from the *branch vocabulary*).

I managed to set up a view that does what it should: each *sector node* shows related *product nodes*. I did this by doing the following (sharing this because this may help others):

1. First of all: make sure that, eventhough both content types use the same vocabulary, **each content type has a *different taxonomy field* that refers to the same vocabulary**. For the *sector content type* we'll call the (taxonomy) field "rel sector", the (taxonomy) field of the *product content type* we'll call "rel product". Both point to the same vocabulary: *branch*.
2. Create a **block** display in your (content) View.
3. **Add a contextual filter: Content NID** (default value: content-ID from
   URL).
4. **Add a relationship: taxonomy terms on node** (check the commonly used
   vocabulary).
5. **Add another relationship: Taxonomy term: Content that uses "rel
   product"**. Tie it to the previously created relationship (relation:
   term, for instance). Make it required.
6. Configure the **Query settings** as follows: *distinct* (to avoid
   duplicates)
7. Open the **title field**, and tie it to the second **relationship** (which
   in this case would be `field_rel_product`).

**Important:**

- Make sure ***not*** to have a **filter criterion based on content type** in your view display, or it will actually block the content you'll need.
- Again, make sure that, eventhough both content types use the same
  vocabulary, each has a different field that refers to the vocabulary.

This works perfect when using common taxonomy terms on one level ànd it works with child terms as well, but in that last case it's required to have all those child terms checked when displaying a *parent node*. And that's exactly what I want to eliminate.

What I'm after is that it should suffice to check the a parent term, and all its children would be displayed as well, without them being checked necessarely.

It's not such a big deal if this isn't possible by design, but could anyone provide the finishing touch if it is please?